# Setting the Desktop colour - always black -

Tags: nvidia, compiz, desktop-environments, colors

## The Setting

I am constantly changing my background image, but occasionally I'd prefer to have a plane colour like a light blue or white.

## The Problem

I right click on the Desktop, select **Change Desktop Background** and choose an image and instantly the Desktop changes to show the selected image in full colour. However, when I choose a colour, the screen turns black, no matter what colour I choose.

This happens if I choose a solid colour or a gradient

## My Set-up

I have a Sony Vaio, 4GiB SDRAM, GeForce 8400M GT/PCIe/SSE2, 64-bit.  and how can I fix it

## The Question

What would cause this problem, and how can I fix it?